# How to call a webapi rest service from WinRT / Store app

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, webservice-client

I have a simple requirement: I need to access a restfull Webapi securely that receives some data to logon and then returns some data:

I have to send some data:

```
public class CredentialsModel
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
            public string ExchangeRoomId {get; set; }
}
```

And I want a list of Appointment to be returned:

```
public class Appointment
{
    public Guid AppointmentId { get; set; }
    public string AppointmentExchangeId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do this in a Windows 8.1 Store / WinRT app?

Comment: I've search a lot of samples. But most of them are about WCF or just a GET or POST but without returning some data. Other go about .NET framework, but WinRT is just a subset of .NET, so that code doesn't work either. Trief PostAsync, but I'm not able to deserialize the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
    using (var httpFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter())
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpFilter))
        {
            Uri requestUri = new Uri("");
            string json = await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(CredentialsModel);
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, new HttpStringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json"));
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Ok)
            {
                var responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var deserializedResponse = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<IEnumerable<Appointment>>(responseAsString);
            }
        }
    }
```

As the json converter I use [Json.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: You saved my day (or actually: days). Works fine, thanks. (BTW: I left out the httpfilter, because the compiler was complaining about that)